# Get type of object property value by Object property key and Object type

Tags: typescript

I have the type of an object and a key for objects of that type. How to get the type of the corresponding value to the key?

I have the following function:

```
function toPartial<T>(key: keyof T, value: T[typeof key]): Partial<T> {
  const partial: Partial<T> = {};
  partial[key] = value;
  return partial;
}
```

The current type of `value` is wrong because it includes the types of all keys with the type of the key.

Example:

```
type ExampleType = {
  id: string,
  amount: number
}

const key = "amount";
const value = "abc"

toPartial<ExampleType>(key, value); // with my implementation there is no type error, but it should because a string is not assignable to `amount` of `Example type`.
```

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be functional? You could just use a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) or a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) instead: https://tsplay.dev/wE4bvW — If this answers your question, I can write it up as an answer. If not, can you explain what criteria isn't met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished entirely via [inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) of arguments, but it will require a [higher-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) helper function in order to create the appropriate [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

> This is because TypeScript doesn't currently allow for supplying only *some* generic type parameters: it's either all or none at the moment. You can read more about this at the following GitHub issue: [microsoft/TypeScript#10571 - Allow skipping some generics when calling a function with multiple generics](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571)

Here's what that helper function would look like:

```ts
type PartialFactoryFn<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> =
  <K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(key: K, value: V) => Partial<T>;

/** @returns the `toPartial` function that you described in your question */
function createPartialFactory <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(): PartialFactoryFn<T> {
  return (key, value) => {
    const partial: Partial<T> = {};
    partial[key] = value;
    return partial;
  };
}
```

You can use it with your example type and values this way:

```ts
type Example = {
  amount: number;
  id: string;
};

const partialExampleError = createPartialFactory<Example>()("amount", "abc"); /* Error
                                                                      ~~~~~
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345) */

const partialExample = createPartialFactory<Example>()("amount", 10); // ok

partialExample.amount;
             //^? (property) amount?: number | undefined
partialExample.id;
             //^? (property) id?: string | undefined
```

And if you want to create a dedicated function that is constrained by a specific type (e.g. your example type), you can also write it this way:

```ts
const toPartialExample = createPartialFactory<Example>();

toPartialExample("amount", "abc"); /* Error
                           ~~~~~
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345) */

toPartialExample("amount", 10); // ok
```

[Code in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwGJwMbAPYIgYB2APACpQQAewExAJgM5QBKE2BDpMCekSEAGkIIADRQArsQDWxPAHdiAPmVQAvACgoUUkKq16zKDNF4AZlHISAagbqMW5ANpCAusoAUpkAC4oQhIAbuiSEP42AJQaavBIqGgUygDcmpoA9ABUmVAAAggQwJIIxCzAABbQAAb4cSjoVVDm0rjIeMRQFXDAUCB4klAMEEzYCMgARhAMUMgdfcVQAI5hTCjtUJnpms3EreujEN0QdQlYuAQgupQ0DsbsnAjcvPwQgiLiUrLySqqekf4ndBnfCEEhJKAAb20UAKRRKUG8omCoQg0XUaihOh0nFKPTAiHqaABBIS4PUkIAvqksVB8fF0M4fG4NFAQmgwtSsbDih06YTOVTNBS0qBIFAAKLUOAAWzAaGg5MxUBl-WIwH8xEk0smCE5yAY-lWY2IAHNUoLNDjVrSSehJTK5RBxQg+AgWQcjoDMDgQSBSPbZfKvJFPAAiFXSYChiTh8bYUORZJQLISl0EaE0zNZ7M53N5-M5gB+xeLmgAgggTVr6D0LJ1wNAAORG2YmxszFjyHpwJhMZAm4hwcbyzp4G0IGWFV5QOuipua7WvRsAOk8ACYAMwAFgArNFNmkrXjbWgA473QVPSfgRd-VLAxBg2GI2ro1AAIwABkTyfSM5kaR8gkZ7ysuL7AJy+bpOkAB6AD8mhAXa96Osu+qQXm0HwYe7TWrUJ4gQqUAenQXo3oQd4OkGfypJo+H0qeKHys+0qqlGMZDvGP4ps6roZgWBYlqWFZVtKNYzpYc5QM2wDGm2HZQF2yq9v2g7DtA+DjpOdBurODbSQuOoruu257hsWx0XgXqESxbFvl+3F-ngAFAA)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that works:

```
function toPartial<T, U extends keyof T>(key: U, value: T[U]): Partial<Pick<T, U>> {
  const partial: Partial<T> = {};
  partial[key] = value;
  return partial;
}

type ExampleType = {
  id: string,
  amount: number
}

const foo = toPartial<ExampleType, "amount">("amount", 3);
```

The value is linked to the key. Also the return type might be improved by using `Pick` !

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=59&pln=12&pc=37#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOAFAhgJ1ugNgHgBUAaRAVUQFMAPKSsAEwGdEBrSgTzmEUID4AFOw4AucqQBueEJTGEA2mQC6ASjEZsMPPlQwIrIqTJ8+iAN4AoRIggImURAAcsOXOpdaC-RAF5zAXwBuKycPPHlhJV9EKVwZYOtMSigQTCRnTTxg-wsLKA5HSkQAUWp0AFtHXEpCAqK-S2sYBjF7TBgwAHNiEIq4cCgxMBBygCNKTAsci1swe0RgODholA1XfFKKqpq60gAiPoG9wQPy-rAoPdIAZhVAoA)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work if we have the key as variable

Comment: Then without the key being typed accordingly, the compiler won't be able to infer the typing.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It appears to me that part of the question criteria is to **not** narrow the type using [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys). Also, I think your [current](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75087975/1) playground link is broken.